# Chart.js scatter charts: Is there a way to indicate that datapoints of two data sets are on top of each other?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have two datasets which can include data points with the same x and y value. When I hover over them in the rendered chart I can see that one drawn point contains several data points from several datasets.

Is there a way to make this visible without having to hover over the point? I'm thinking of changing the color/border of a drawn point when there are several datasets included in that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the scriptable options to give the point a different background color if there are multiple points in that spot

Example:

```js
const overlappingPointsCheck = (x, y) => {
  if (!x.parsed) return;

  let overlappingPoints = false;
  for (let i = x.datasetIndex + 1; i < x.chart.data.datasets.length; i++) {
    if (x.parsed.y === x.chart.data.datasets[i].data[x.parsed.x]) {
      overlappingPoints = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return overlappingPoints;
}

const multipleEntrieColor = 'purple';

const options = {
  type: 'scatter',
  data: {
    labels: [0, 1, 2, 3],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 11, 3, 5],
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: (x, y) => {
          return overlappingPointsCheck(x, y) ? multipleEntrieColor : 'red';
        }
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8],
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: (x, y) => {
          return overlappingPointsCheck(x, y) ? multipleEntrieColor : 'blue';
        }
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [2, 9, 7, 8],
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: (x, y) => {
          return overlappingPointsCheck(x, y) ? multipleEntrieColor : 'green';
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {}
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.2.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This seems like what I need :)

Comment: I just realized: Is there a way to get the rendered x/y value of a point in v2.8?

Comment: Yeah, in v2 the scriptable option should only have 1 argument, which has the data and dataset indexes and the chart instanses so you will need to use those 2 to get the right data out of the chart instance